# Encoding a channel with Huffman Code

Tags: information-theory

I have a random source which is with no memory and have this alphabet (A,B,C).
Each symbol in the alphabet has a probability ( A = 0.5, B= 0.25, C = 0.25)
It's given that each message including exactly 60 chars.
And need to fund a Huffman code when we coding a pair of chars and the channel gets those chars ( 0, 1, 2).

I know how to do it when the channel gets only two chars (0,1).

I created the pairs of chars, and calculated the probability of each pair

```
AA 0.25
AB 0.125
AC 0.125
BA 0.125
BB 0.0625
BC 0.0625
CA 0.125
CB 0.0625
CC 0.0625
```

after that I sorted the list and the final result is :

```
AA 0.25
AB 0.125
AC 0.125
BA 0.125
CA 0.125
BB 0.0625
BC 0.0625
CB 0.0625
CC 0.0625
```

now I know how to solve it when the channel gets only (0,1) but How to solve it when
the channel get (0,1,2)? 
how to create the Huffman code with three channel symbols?

Comment: The algorithm to construct a $n$-ary Huffman code is exactly the same as in the binary case, except that at each step you take the $n$ least probable values instead of the two least probable.

Comment: You also need to add dummy symbols (with probability 0) to ensure that in the last step, you have $n$ symbols remaining. That is, with $k$ steps left, $1+k(n-1)$ symbols should be remaining.

Comment: right! I didn't solve this kind of questions a long time and I was confused with Fanno :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do an n-ary Huffman code, you can simply use the algorithm used in the binary case, but taking the n least probable values instead of the 2 least probable.

However, there is something more to do before the algorithm : in order to build a well-constructed n-ary Huffman tree, you need your **number of possbilities to be congruent to 1 modulo n-1** (because at each iteration, you compress n nodes into a single one, as if you removed n-1 possibilities).

In your case, you have 9 possibilities and n-1 = 2 so you are good to go, but if it wasn't the case, you would simply have to add another with probability 0.

Comment: right! I didn't solve this kind of questions a long time and I was confused with Fanno :)

Thank you for refreshing my memory :)

Comment: You're welcome ! :)